# How to extract the text between the tags when the user clicks on anchor tag in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a iPhone app which displays a HTML content like below.

[**I am Clicking Google Now**](http://google.com)

When the user clicks on the hyperlink I want to extract the text under that hyperlink i.e "I am clicking google now" and store it in a variable.

How to extract the text between anchor Tags when a user clicks on a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$("body").on("click","a",function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

or if you know the id of the link :

```
<a id="myId"  href="www.foo.bar">cancel</a>

$("#myId").on("click",function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```